# iPhone not receiving notifications (and calls) for some apps

Tags: ios, notifications

I have recently noticed that I am missing notifications for some apps on my iPhone 8 Plus. The onset of the issue might coincide with updating to iOS 14, but I am not sure.

I don't know how many apps have been affected by the issue, but I know that Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp and Viber don't receive them. Not only that, but I don't even get incoming calls from these apps. Sometimes, if I have just opened the app I will receive the call/notification afterwards, and if I kill the app it would stop working again. But even that is not consistent.

Other apps like Messages, Twitter, Reddit, etc. seem to get all notifications, so the issue might be isolated to VoIP/chat apps. But again, I'm simply not sure.

I have checked and re-checked my notification and call settings and they are all fine. This isn't surprising since I have changed notning from when it used to work. I have also tried re-installing the apps with no luck.

I was hoping that iOS 14.3 would have a fix for this, but it's still not working after the update. My wife's iPhone 11 Pro Max is running the same apps, with same settings on same iOS version, and she has no issues.

Comment: `Notifications` settings seems to be the obvious suspect but since you've checked it, the next obvious place to check is `Settings` >  `General`  >  `Background App Refresh` and check if the apps are enabled. (I have noticed that sometimes ios updates do mess up your old settings).

Comment: @sfxedit Thank you for the suggestion. I've checked it, and is turned on for all apps.

Comment: Try out the [first 4 steps listed in this guide here](https://www.tenorshare.com/ios-12/ios-12-notification-not-working.html). NOTE: Do not try the 5th step. That's a drastic last resort, and there are safer ways to do it than the one described..

Comment: I had tried all of those already except for resetting the network settings. I've tried that too now and it didn't help. I suspect there is a more specific issue at play here. As I said, notifications work for most of the apps.

Comment: Yes, I have come across many others complaining about similar issues on ios 14 and it does seem to be some bug. You could try `Settings` > `General` > `Reset` > `Erase All Settings` (note that this will reset all changes you made to Settings to the default and you will have to modify them all over again) and see if it helps. Or as a last resort, you can try erasing all data and resetting but this will delete all data on your iDevice.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Even did a factory reset: still doesn't work !

Comment: I have the same problem and tried every step short of a factory reset, to no effect. I noticed that the apps that don't get notifications have actived notifications on my phone, but deactivated notifications on my watch. If I activate the watch notifications, they seem work.